# How to use gon.watch with angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I using [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem in my app.

```
@users = User.all
gon.watch.users = @users
```

And i using angular to display list of users

```
<div ng-repeat = "user in users">
  {{ user.name }}
</div>
```

in Angular Ctrl:

```
gon.watch('users', interval: 1000, renewUsers)
```

The question is what i should write within `renewUsers` function to update list of users inside my ng-repeat

```
renewUsers = (...) ->
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

renewUsers should update the scope with new data. Sth like:

```
renewUsers = (data) ->
  $scope.apply ->
    $scope.users = data
```